# Precise use of Neumann B.C.s in the Nambu-Goto action

Tags: string-theory, boundary-conditions

Sometime ago I posted this: [Logical consistence in Neumann BC in the Nambu-Goto action](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/766999/251344), whose answer was not helpful to me. Basically in classical string theory with the Nambu-Goto action, we have some kind of momentum density given by

$$P^\sigma_\mu = - \frac{T_0}{c} \frac{(\dot{X} \cdot X') \dot{X}_\mu - (\dot{X})^2 X'_\mu}{\sqrt{(\dot{X} \cdot X')^2  - (\dot{X})^2(X')^2  } } \tag1.$$

If we call the numerator by $F_\mu$, we can write $(1)$ as

$$P^\sigma_\mu = - \frac{T_0}{c} \frac{F_\mu}{\sqrt{F(X') } }, \ F(X') = F_\mu X'^\mu \tag2.$$

This is part of a boundary term which I intend to make zero as a boundary condition, but actually what I need is to say that the limit of this $P^\sigma$ goes to zero as $\sigma \to 0,\pi$. But the limit of $P^\sigma$ being zero implies the limit of numerator $F$ is zero.

The person that answered my first post claimed that I could show that in the limit that F goes to zero, the quotient above goes to zero because $F_\mu$ decreases faster than the denominator. Although this is clear to me in an Euclidean case, in the present problem it is not obvious because I'm using the Minkowski scalar product. I'd appreciate any help.